# mysql isolation level of select query (insert visibility)

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two threads:

First thread make `select * from big_table` and itarate over it.

Second thread inserts a row in this table (after the select of 1st thread), while first thread itarates big result set. First thread continue to iterate over table.

**In the end of iteration does first thread pick up the value inserted by the second thread row or not and why?**

Comment: Test it yourself. In one session insert records every 1 second, an in the other session run this query: `select t.* from table where sleep( 5 ) = 0` which will simulate a long running query. Test it using different session parameters and engines. There are two engines (MyIsam, InnoDb) / two autocommit modes (0/1) / 4 isolation levels / 2 modes of consistent snapshot (START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT) - total 32 test cases for each combination.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/) out:-

> One more thing to keep into account – INSERT … SELECT actually
>   performs read in locking mode and so partially bypasses versioning and
>   retrieves latest committed row. So even if you’re operation in
>   REPEATABLE-READ mode, this operation will be performed in
>   READ-COMMITTED

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what does that exactly means.